# Finding a point in the relative interior of the convex hull of a set of integer-valued vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, linear-programming, integer-programming

Let $X \subset \mathbb{Z}^n$ be the set of integer-valued vectors satisfying a system of linear constraints. We can suppose that $X$ is the set of integral points in a given polyhydral set $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

1. Is there a polynomial time algorithm to find one point (any point) in the relative interior of the convex hull of $X$ (if any)?
2. Suppose that you are given a point $x \in Y$. Is there a polynomial time algorithm to indicate whether this point is in the relative interior of the convex hull of $X$?
3. Assuming that finding such a point is computationally difficult, what could be a good heuristic to find such a point given $X$ or $Y$?

Note that the convex hull of $X$ is a subset of $Y$.

Comment: Almost always, if $x$ and $y$ are distinct and belong to $X$, then their average will be in the interior of the convex hull of $X$ (the exceptions occur when $x$ and $y$ belong to a proper face, which is usually unlikely, unless you have a simplex). If $X$ is finite, then the average of all of them  (or any weighted average, provided every element has nonzero weight) will also be in the interior.

Comment: @DavidHandelman Thanks. So basically it is enough to select two points from $X$ which *do not belong to a proper face* and find their average. How to say whether the selected points $x$ and $y$ satisfy this property? Is there a particular method to find such points? For example, can we select $x$ arbitrarily and $y$ based on some (polynomial) algorithm that makes sure it does not belong to a facet that includes $x$?